# null LIKE '%text%'?

Tags: sql, oracle, null, sql-like

I'm missing many records due to the condition `not like '%TEST%'` althought that field contains a `NULL` value.

```
select * 
from credit_case cc
left join (select skp_case, name_full from client) cl on cc.skp_case = cl.skp_case
where cl.name_full not like '%TEST%'
```

Table `credit_case` contains full data whereas table `client` does not.

When I re-write it as

```
select * 
from credit_case cc
left join (select skp_case, name_full from client 
           where name_full not like '%TEST%') cl on cc.skp_case = cl.skp_case
```

records from `credit_case` are not lost.
Why is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `null` is never equal to another value, including `null`.
- `null` is never unequal to another value, including `null`.
- `null` is never like another value, including `null`.
- `null` is never unlike another value, including `null`.

The only way to do comparisons with `null` is to use `is null` or `is not null`.  None of these queries will ever return a row.

```
select *
  from table
 where column = null;

select *
  from table
 where column != null;

select *
  from table
 where column like null;

select *
  from table
 where column not like null;
```

You would need to explicitly include an `is null` or an `is not null` clause

```
where (   cl.name_full not like '%TEST%'
       or cl.name_full is null)
```

will return the rows with `null` values for `name_full`.

Comment: @Andrew - `isnull` isn't a function that exists in Oracle.  It exists in other databases like SQL Server.  Oracle also treats the empty string as `null` in a `varchar2` column unlike other databases.

Comment: You are extremely right, I completely missed the oracle tag. My bad.

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave for the solution!!

Comment: I've got an error An attempt was made to insert NULL into previously listed objects.

Comment: @HuyR - I don't follow.  Your question has to do with a `select`, not an `insert`.  If you are trying to insert the data this query returns into another table where `name_full` is declared as `not null` then you'd obviously have a problem if the query returns `null` values...

Answer (score 0):

On the first case, there's a condition clause that will filter out some of records from the result.

On the second case, there's no condition clause on the master table. What you're doing is actually

```
select * 
from credit_case cc
left join [SUBTABLE]
```

so that would definitely give you a complete list of the master table, `credit_case`

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, left join is returning all rows and then the where clause is filtering out rows due to Nulls

In the second case the where clause is filtering out  rows due to nulls. Then the left join is adding them back in.
If you run EXPLAIN PLAN,you can see the order of operations, whether the filtering due to null is happening first or the inclusion due to left join is happening

Answer (score 0):

When you are evaluating NULL AND or OR Condition the result is always false.

```
select * 
from credit_case cc
left join (select skp_case, name_full from client) cl on cc.skp_case = cl.skp_case
where cl.name_full not like '%TEST%'
```

Here left join on client results in cl.name_full as NULLS for cases where record is not present in credit_case.

Try this you will understand :

```
select cl.name_full
from credit_case cc
left join (select skp_case, name_full from client) cl on cc.skp_case = cl.skp_case
```

All NULL records are the ones that are omitted from the query result.

On the other hand, for the second case, when you re-write as

```
select * 
from credit_case cc
left join (select skp_case, name_full from client 
           where name_full not like '%TEST%') cl on cc.skp_case = cl.skp_case
```

Here assuming name_full is not NULL, all records not having '%TEST%' in name_full is shown. And NULL is not evaluated with '%TEST%' here.